# assert presence of a text in the view file returned by controller.

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I have a simple test controller.

```
package taglibexample

class HelloWorldController {

    def index() {       

        render(view: "index",  model: [id:2])
    }
}
```

The view that the above controller renders is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title> Hello World </title>
</head>

<body>

<h1> Hello World! ${ id } </h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Now, i want to test this controller method and assert for the presence of the text "Hello World! 2". The code i have so far and which didn't work is as follows:

```
package taglibexample

import static org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.*

class HelloTests {

    def controller


    @Before
    void setUp() {

        controller = new HelloWorldController()
    }


    @Test
    void testSomething() {

        def model = controller.index()

        assertTrue controller.response.getContentAsString().contains("Hello World! 2") 


    }

}
```

how can i accomplish this? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Grails documentation seems to declare this in a very clear way, choose the right one for your grails version

- 3.x: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers
- 2.x: http://docs.grails.org/2.5.0/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers
- 1.x: http://docs.grails.org/1.3.6/guide/single.html#9.2%20Integration%20Testing

For example take a look of this example in grails 2.5.5:

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(SimpleController)
class SimpleControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "test hello"() {
        when:
        controller.hello()

        then:
        response.text == 'hello'
    }
}
```

It tests the the actual response that is generated by the framework. In this case its very simple word, but it can be rendered view not the name of the view

Comment: sorry i only find asserting view name or asserting models returned from controllers. I want to assert the presence of a text in the view file returned from controller. i am using Grails 2.2.

Comment: All the documentations show how this is done exactly.

I've updated my answer

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer.  The test that you cited above will not work for the scenario described in the question.  The test cited above would work if the controller were doing something like `render 'hello'`.